# Transparent status bar hides my navigation menu

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am using the code below for hiding status bar:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat)
{
   // for covering the full screen in android..
   Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.LayoutNoLimits,
   WindowManagerFlags.LayoutNoLimits);

   // clear FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS flag:
   Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.TranslucentStatus);

   Window.SetStatusBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);


}
```

The problem is that it also hides my bottom navigation menu

[image]

Is there any way for solving that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you used `WindowManagerFlags.LayoutNoLimits`，resulting in the back key, menu key button bar and page content overlap.

You could change like:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat)
    {
        Window.SetStatusBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
        var uiVisibility = SystemUiFlags.LayoutFullscreen | SystemUiFlags.LayoutStable;
        FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.Content).SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)uiVisibility ;
    }
```